# Global var for nested nodeJS query

Tags: node.js

Please help me to solve this problem :

I have problem in accessing a variable in nodeJS nested client.query

This is the code :

```
client.query("SELECT distinct(nip) as nip, nama from history_talenta", function(err,rows_final){    

        var inner_counter=0;
        var kumulatif_talenta='';
        var naikgrade=false;
        var finalJSON = [];
        for(var p=0; p < rows_final.length; p++) {
            client.query("SELECT h.nip, COUNT(*) as jumlah, h.talenta FROM history_talenta h, bobot_talent b where h.nip = '"+rows_final[p].nip+"' and h.talenta = b.talent GROUP BY h.talenta ORDER BY b.bobot DESC", function(err,rows_jlh_talenta){  
                for(var k=0; k<rows_jlh_talenta.length; k++){
                    if(inner_counter<1){
                        kumulatif_talenta += rows_jlh_talenta[k].jumlah+" "+rows_jlh_talenta[k].talenta;
                    }else{
                        kumulatif_talenta += ", "+rows_jlh_talenta[k].jumlah+" "+rows_jlh_talenta[k].talenta;
                    }
                    client.query("SELECT count(syarat) as syarat FROM syarat_naik_grade where syarat = '"+kumulatif_talenta+"'", function(err,result_check){    

                        if(result_check[0].syarat>0){
                            naikgrade = true;

                           //array
                           var myObj2 = {
                               "nip" : rows_final[p].nip, **<== nip is undefined**
                               "nama" : rows_final[p].nama, **<== nama is undefined**   
                               "perolehan_talenta" : kumulatif_talenta, 
                               "is_naik_grade_normal" : naikgrade 
                            };

                            // Send Result to JSON
                            finalJSON.push( myObj2 );
                        }
                    });

                    inner_counter++;
                }
                kumulatif_talenta='';
                inner_counter = 0;
            });



            // Reset variable
            kumulatif_talenta="";
            inner_counter=0;
            naikgrade=false;
        }

        // Send to browser
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(finalJSON, null, 4));
        res.render('pages/hasilchecknaikgrade',{ data2 : JSON.stringify(finalJSON, null, 4), data : req.session.user, datarole : req.session.role, moment : moment } );
});
```

The problem is, How to access "nip" and "nama" variable, from inner nested client.query above ?

The "nip" and "nama" var are the return value from the first query / top client.query.

Thank you

Comment: Do you get proper value of rows_final?

Comment: No, I cannot get rows_final either

Comment: Mean your top query is not working?

Comment: my top query is working, the rows_final not working inside the inner query

Comment: Can you show first item value of rows_final?

Comment: okay thank you @abdulbarik i misstype  rows_final[p].nip should be rows_final[0].nip.